# ladspa-foo-plugins – where are the plugins located?

Tags: plugins, location

I installed the plugins mentioned (sudo apt-get install ladspa-foo-plugins), but Audacity doesn't find them. They are not located in /usr/lib/ladspa.

How can I find out where installed files from a package are located?

Answer (score 1):

The package [ladspa-foo-plugins](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ladspa-foo-plugins) [image: Install ladspa-foo-plugins] contains documentation files **only** which will be installed to `/usr/share/doc/ladspa-foo-plugins/`.

The actual plugins need to be downloaded, compiled, and installed from source. This can e.g. be done from here:

- [foo-plugins source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/source/precise/foo-plugins)

Or from the following [ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them):

- [ppa:kxstudio-team/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-team/+archive/ppa)

<sub>As this is not what we expect from a package this should be [reported as bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).</sub>